# In Rails how does one find disassociated records in a HABTM relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, join

I have a HABTM relationship between Videos and Campaigns in Rails which means the association is stored in a join table. I want to find all the Videos that do NOT have an associated campaign. What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Thank you for looking =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Video.all(:include => :campaigns, :conditions => ["campaigns.id IS ?", nil])
```

the `:include` will do a left join to the associated table so anything without a campaign should have `NULL` values for the campaign field values.

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby way:

```
Video.all.select {|v| v.campaigns.empty?}
```

I think this is more elegant if you use it standalone in a method. However, I would recommend to write a [named scope](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html#M000831) for that. Then again, Geoffs version is the right one:

```
named_scope :campaign_less, :include => :campaigns, :conditions => ["campaigns.id IS ?", nil]
```

Besides, Geoffs solution is probably more efficient as it is more lowlevel.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL way:

```
Videos.select_by_sql("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT video_id FROM campaign_videos)")
```

Comment: Although why would you want to write pure sql in an environment which provides you the tools and the means to not do it,